# maven still lists excluded dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a maven [project](https://github.com/rdp/maven_exclusions) with these dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

If I run `mvn tree` it still shows the excluded artifact:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ testArtifact ---
[INFO] testGroup:testArtifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1200-jdbc41:compile
[INFO]    +- com.github.dblock.waffle:waffle-jna:jar:1.7:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.7:runtime   ** <--- BAD ONE
```

And if I run things like dependency:copy-dependencies or the shaded jar plugin, they all pull in the unwanted jar.

Am I missing something?

Using maven 3.6.0

Comment: why close this?  Typo's are legit problems, too! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groupId is incorrect. Should be org.slf4j instead of org.slf4 (the j is missing).

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see it somehow :)